# Help with PopUp Function

Tags: javascript, popup

OK guys... I'm missing something so basic here that it hurts to even ask.  Trying to write a basic function that will pop up a window.  The author can pass in 3 variables... an ID, a height, and a width.  My javascript function looks like this:

```
function mypopup(pid,h,w)
{
    mywindow = window.open('http://www.test.com?pid=" + pid + "', 'mywindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",resizable=no,scrollbars=no')
}
```

On the HTML file, this is the structure of my links:

```
<a href="#" onclick="mypopup("K1i2phr4eVEf4BexlfBgym_WM6Ig7U9a","436","503")">text</a>
```

Can't get it to work... I know I'm missing something easy, can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call like that : syntax error

```
  function mypopup(pid, h, w) {
    mywindow = window.open('http://www.test.com?pid=' + pid , 'mywindow', 'toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
}
<a href="#" onclick='mypopup("K1i2phr4eVEf4BexlfBgym_WM6Ig7U9a","436","503")'>text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mywindow = window.open('http://www.test.com?pid=' + pid, 'mywindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width="' + w + '",height="' + h + '", resizable=no,scrollbars=no')
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be passing the variables through to the function.  When I do this, the querystring contains extra characters (quotes) and the window size isn't taking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="mypopup('K1i2phr4eVEf4BexlfBgym_WM6Ig7U9a','436','503')">text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
<a href="javascript: mypopup('K1i2phr4eVEf4BexlfBgym_WM6Ig7U9a','436','503')">text</a>
```